# iOS like over scroll effect on Android

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation, android-scrollview

I want to implement the iOS-like bounce overscroll effect in my app.

I came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13391248/3500826) which suggests creating a custom `ScrollView`. But the problem is that when I am scrolling up and down fast it's working fine but as soon as I pull the bottom or top of the screen it's just stuck and the effect is not working anymore.

As an example of the kind of animation I want to achieve you can look at this:

[image]

This is the code I currently have:

```
public class ObservableScrollView extends ScrollView
{
    private static final int MAX_Y_OVERSCROLL_DISTANCE = 150;

    private Context mContext;
    private int mMaxYOverscrollDistance;

    public ObservableScrollView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        initBounceScrollView();
    }

    public ObservableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        initBounceScrollView();
    }

    public ObservableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mContext = context;
        initBounceScrollView();
    }

    private void initBounceScrollView()
    {
        //get the density of the screen and do some maths with it on the max overscroll distance
        //variable so that you get similar behaviors no matter what the screen size

        final DisplayMetrics metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        final float density = metrics.density;

        mMaxYOverscrollDistance = (int) (density * MAX_Y_OVERSCROLL_DISTANCE);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX, int scrollY, int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY, int maxOverScrollX, int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent)
    {
        //This is where the magic happens, we have replaced the incoming maxOverScrollY with our own custom variable mMaxYOverscrollDistance;
        return super.overScrollBy(deltaX, deltaY, scrollX, scrollY, scrollRangeX, scrollRangeY, maxOverScrollX, mMaxYOverscrollDistance, isTouchEvent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I have quickly put together a simple solution based on a `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior`. It's not perfect, you can maybe spend some time fine tuning it a bit, but it's not bad. Anyway the result should look something like this:

[image]

As a small side note before I start with the answer: I strongly recommend that you use the `NestedScrollView` from the support library instead of a normal `ScrollView`. They are identical in any way, but the `NestedScrollView` implements correct nested scrolling behaviour on lower API levels.

Anyway let's start with my answer: The solution I came up with would work with any scrollable container, be it a `ScrollView`, `ListView` or `RecyclerView` and you don't need to subclass any `Views` to implement it.

First you need to add Google's Design Support Library to your project if you aren't already using it:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
```

Remember that if you aren't targeting API level 25 (which you should by the way) then you need to include the newest version for your API level (eg. `compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'` for API level 24).

Whatever scrollable container you are using needs to wrapped in a `CoordinatorLayout` in your layout. In my example I am using a `NestedScrollView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- content -->

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The `CoordinatorLayout` allows you to assign a `Behavior` to its direct child views. In this case we are going to assign a `Behavior` to the `NestedScrollView` which is going implement the overscroll bounce effect.

Let's just take a look at the code of the `Behavior`:

```
public class OverScrollBounceBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View> {

    private int mOverScrollY;

    public OverScrollBounceBehavior() {
    }

    public OverScrollBounceBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, View child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        mOverScrollY = 0;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, View child, View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
        if (dyUnconsumed == 0) {
            return;
        }

        mOverScrollY -= dyUnconsumed;
        final ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) target;
        final int count = group.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View view = group.getChildAt(i);
            view.setTranslationY(mOverScrollY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, View child, View target) {
        final ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) target;
        final int count = group.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View view = group.getChildAt(i);
            ViewCompat.animate(view).translationY(0).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Explaining what a `Behavior` is and how they work is beyond the scope of this answer so I am just going to quickly explain what the above code does. The `Behavior` intercepts all scroll events that happen in the direct children of the `CoordinatorLayout`. In the `onStartNestedScroll()` method we return `true` since we are interested in any scroll events. In `onNestedScroll()` we look at the `dyUnconsumed` parameter which tells us how much of the vertical scroll was not consumed by the scrolling container (in other words overscroll) and then translate the children of the scrolling container by that amount. Since we are just getting delta values we need to sum up all of them in the `mOverscrollY` variable. `onStopNestedScroll()` is called when the scrolling event stops. This is when we animate all children of the scrolling container back to their original position.

To assign the `Behavior` to the `NestedScrollView` we need to use the `layout_behavior` xml attribute and pass in the full class name of the `Behavior` we want to use. In my example the above class is in the package `com.github.wrdlbrnft.testapp` so I have to set `com.github.wrdlbrnft.testapp.OverScrollBounceBehavior` as value. `layout_behavior` is a custom attribute of the `CoordinatorLayout` so we need to prefix it with the correct namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.github.wrdlbrnft.testapp.OverScrollBounceBehavior">

        <!-- content -->

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Notice the namespace I added on the `CoordinatorLayout` and the `app:layout_behavior` attribute I added on the `NestedScrollView`.

And that is all you have to do! While this answer turned out to be longer than I intended I skipped over some of the basics concering the `CoordinatorLayout` and `Behaviors`. So if you are unfamiliar with these or have any other further questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi @Xaver Kapler thanks for your update. And one more doubt is, in this  we manually pulling down and up for bouncing. But in the attached screen gif, if we scroll and when it reaches bottom, it bounce back. Same at top also.i checked by downloading the app.  How it can been achieved in scrollview?

Comment: @Shadow sure it is. All you need is same math to clamp the over scroll in an exponential way.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Can you add the relevant code for fling?

Comment: @Bhargav This is just supposed to be a simple example showing one way how one can go about implementing this. Adding more complex scrolling and flinging logic would make it a lot more complicated and make the answer less useful. This isn't supposed to be a ready made solution which everyone can just copy and paste - it's supposed to demonstrate the concept. If you want something finished which you can just use in your app then look for a library - you should find plenty on GitHub.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I feel I shouldn't create a new question for this, I want to understand how you handle velocities in onFling, I feel adding it conceptually (no need of code) to this answer should make your answer more complete. Basically you have the velocityY, how do you determine the distance now?

Comment: @Bhargav just make a new question and link to it here in the comments

Comment: I have write a demo about CoordiantorLayout Behavior implement and optimize the code. Not same over scroll effect, but it can show you how to use Behavior Here is a demo [Link](https://github.com/MARGI3/StretchTopNestedScrollView), and [Gif](https://gfycat.com/HotInsistentBuckeyebutterfly)

Comment: In my case it crashes with ```android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #535: Could not inflate Behavior subclass```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to **Xaver Kapeller**, I have written my solution with overriding fling and little additions, using **kotlin** and **androidx**

[image]

Add coordinator dependency

```
implementation "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0"
```

Create a new class that extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat

class OverScrollBehavior(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet)
: CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View>() {

companion object {
    private const val OVER_SCROLL_AREA = 4
}

private var overScrollY = 0

override fun onStartNestedScroll(
    coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout,
    child: View,
    directTargetChild: View,
    target: View,
    axes: Int,
    type: Int
): Boolean {
    overScrollY = 0
    return true
}

override fun onNestedScroll(
    coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout,
    child: View,
    target: View,
    dxConsumed: Int,
    dyConsumed: Int,
    dxUnconsumed: Int,
    dyUnconsumed: Int,
    type: Int,
    consumed: IntArray
) {
    if (dyUnconsumed == 0) {
        return
    }

    overScrollY -= (dyUnconsumed/OVER_SCROLL_AREA)
    val group = target as ViewGroup
    val count = group.childCount
    for (i in 0 until count) {
        val view = group.getChildAt(i)
        view.translationY = overScrollY.toFloat()
    }
}

override fun onStopNestedScroll(
    coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout,
    child: View,
    target: View,
    type: Int
) {
    // Smooth animate to 0 when the user stops scrolling
    moveToDefPosition(target)
}

override fun onNestedPreFling(
    coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout,
    child: View,
    target: View,
    velocityX: Float,
    velocityY: Float
): Boolean {
    // Scroll view by inertia when current position equals to 0
    if (overScrollY == 0) {
        return false
    }
    // Smooth animate to 0 when user fling view
    moveToDefPosition(target)
    return true
}

private fun moveToDefPosition(target: View) {
    if (overScrollY == 0) {
        return
    }
    val group = target as ViewGroup
    val count = group.childCount
    for (i in 0 until count) {
        val view = group.getChildAt(i)
        ViewCompat.animate(view)
            .translationY(0f)
            .setInterpolator(AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
            .start()
    }
}

}
```

Create XML file with CoordinatorLayout and NestedScrollView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior=".OverScrollBehavior">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/Lorem"/>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And don't forget to add

```
app:layout_behavior=".OverScrollBehavior" // Or your file name
```

field to your NestedScrollView XML markup

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use library then this **[Bouncy](https://github.com/Valkriaine/bouncy)** is the best library which is the best match with your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

this is work perfectly for me

**Overscroll-decor-android**

**Add the following to your module's build.gradle file:**

```
    dependencies {

  // ...

 compile 'me.everything:overscroll-decor-android:1.0.4' 
}
```

then import

```
import me.everything.android.ui.overscroll.OverScrollDecoratorHelper;
```

now you can set to any view with the following

```
OverScrollDecoratorHelper.setUpStaticOverScroll(scrollView, OverScrollDecoratorHelper.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
```