# React Native scrollview is bouncing only on ios, not Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview, native, bounce

How can I make scrollview bounce on Android ?

From [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#bounces) it seems that scrollview should only bounce on ios?!

Is there another way other than setting `bounces = {true}` ?

Comment: No, on Android, there's no bounce effect like ios

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758635/ios-like-over-scroll-effect-on-android), otherwise it is only a property of `ios` in `react-native`

Comment: Seams like the only solution is to do this in native code thank you