# Remove LazyColumn overscroll effect in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, android-overscoll

I am using version 1.1.0-alpha05 of Jetpack Compose and I wanted to know if there is a way to turn off the scrolling effect for `LazyColumn` like xml (`android:overScrollMode="never"`)?

[image]

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can disable it by providing [`LocalOverscrollConfiguration`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#LocalOverscrollConfiguration()):

```kotlin
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalOverscrollConfiguration provides null
) {
    LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        items(1000) {
            Text(it.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

You can also build it into your theme so that it applies to the entire application:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkThemeColors
    } else {
        LightThemeColors
    }
    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = typography,
        shapes = shapes,
    ) {
        CompositionLocalProvider(
            LocalOverscrollConfiguration provides null,
            content = content
        )
    }
}
```

p.s. in [**1.2.0-rc01**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#LocalOverscrollConfiguration()) `LocalOverScrollConfiguration` has being renamed to `LocalOverscrollConfiguration`

Comment: Is there a way, to create custom overscroll animation something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758635/ios-like-over-scroll-effect-on-android ?

Comment: @slaviboy https://stackoverflow.com/a/70632616/3585796

Comment: @slaviboy Here is the compose way of customising overscrolleffect. https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/OverscrollEffect

Comment: is there any way to add that scroll animation if we have minimum content in the screen because the lazy column won't animate if we have minimum data on the screen @PhilDukhov

Answer (score 0):

For people who have nested `LazyColumn`s:

To remove the unsightly overscroll effect that appears around the nested content, don't forget to set `userScrollEnabled = false`  on it.

Comment: Is there any way to add that scroll animation if we have minimum content on the screen the lazy column won't animate if we have minimum data on the screen

Comment: That's probably its own question - try making a new SO question and filling out with all the details you can muster

Comment: doesn't this disable scrolling?

Comment: @MartyMiller no