# Does Jetpack Compose have the tools to create custom OverscrollEffect?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to create OverscrollEffect in jetpack compose?

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: By default I can see overscroll in `LazyColumn`.

Comment: @Abhimanyu i want to make custom overscroll, like on the left emulator on this gif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overscroll effect can be controlled by the `LocalOverscrollConfiguration`, which currently has the following parameters:

> glowColor - color for the glow effect, if the platform effect is a glow effect, otherwise ignored.
> forceShowAlways - force show overscroll even if content doesn't scroll (is smaller than a scrollable container itself)
> drawPadding - the amount of padding to apply from scrollable container bounds to effect before drawing it

```
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalOverscrollConfiguration provides OverScrollConfiguration(
        glowColor = Color.Gray,
        forceShowAlways = false,
        drawPadding = PaddingValues()
    )
) {
    // effected views
}
```

If you think there should be more parameters, you can let the maintainers know by [creating a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128).

---

p.s. in [**1.2.0-rc01**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.2.0-rc01) `LocalOverScrollConfiguration` has being renamed to `LocalOverscrollConfiguration`