# how to set overscroll color in material 3 (android jetpack compose)?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-design

Not sure if it's called overscroll...
I'm talking about that effect appearing when we try to scroll beyond the limit.

1. what's the name of that?
2. how do I change the color of it?

I've tried reading the docs, but I can't find much since I don't know the actual name of this feature

This is what I'm expecting to see:

[blue overscroll (?) example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/degvX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70632616/13412502) answer, you can wrap the affected elements in the CompositionLocalProvider

```
MaterialTheme(
    colorScheme = colorScheme,
    typography = Typography
){
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalOverscrollConfiguration provides OverscrollConfiguration(
            glowColor = Color.Red
        ),
        content = content
    )
}
```

The glowColor will only be applied if the overscroll platform effect is glow.

From andoid 12, it was changed to stretch so the glowColor will just be ignored