# How to implement bounce effect on jetpack compose Lazy Column

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to implement a bounce "iOS-like" effect on a LazyColumn but have no clue on how to implement it.

Expected result is : [iOS like over scroll effect on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758635/ios-like-over-scroll-effect-on-android) (using RecyclerView) with bounce on top and bottom of the list.

I went through snapper by Chris Bane : https://github.com/chrisbanes/snapper but it doesn't seem to support it.

My guess is that I would need to create some LazyListScope extension but it's hard to figure out.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

> ***That is not possible at the moment `03.14.2022`***

If you see the source code at [`Scrollable.kt`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/Scrollable.kt;l=1?q=Scrollable.kt&sq=&ss=androidx%2Fplatform%2Fframeworks%2Fsupport:compose%2F) class inside the `androidx.compose.foundation.gestures` package there is a extension function `Modifier.scrollable`

```
internal fun Modifier.scrollable(
    state: ScrollableState,
    orientation: Orientation,
    overScrollController: OverScrollController?,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    reverseDirection: Boolean = false,
    flingBehavior: FlingBehavior? = null,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource? = null
): Modifier
```

This method contains [OverScrollController](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/OverScroll.kt;l=30?q=OverScrollController&sq=&ss=androidx%2Fplatform%2Fframeworks%2Fsupport:compose%2F)
that handles the over-scroll functionally, unfortunately this method is internal so we cannot use it outside of its package.

If we see the [Scroll.kt](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/Scroll.kt;l=1?q=Scroll.kt&ss=androidx%2Fplatform%2Fframeworks%2Fsupport:compose%2F) class inside the androidx.compose.foundation package we can see the extension method scroll() that is also private and is used by `Modifier.verticalScroll` and `Modifier.horizontalScroll`
, is using the default over-scroll controller

```
private fun Modifier.scroll(
    state: ScrollState,
    reverseScrolling: Boolean,
    flingBehavior: FlingBehavior?,
    isScrollable: Boolean,
    isVertical: Boolean
) = composed(
    factory = {
        val overScrollController = rememberOverScrollController()
  ...
```

```
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
internal actual fun rememberOverScrollController(): OverScrollController {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val config = LocalOverScrollConfiguration.current
    return remember(context, config) {
        if (config != null) {
            AndroidEdgeEffectOverScrollController(context, config)
        } else {
            NoOpOverscrollController
        }
    }
}
```

At this moment we can only disable the default over-scroll configurations as seen in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69468212/remove-lazycolumn-overscroll-effect-in-jetpack-compose). Or set out custom configurations, that can only set color and offset and is only available for API < 31

```
 CompositionLocalProvider(
     LocalOverScrollConfiguration provides OverScrollConfiguration(
         glowColor = Color.Red, forceShowAlways = true, PaddingValues(10.dp)
     )
 ) {
     // your row, colum
}
```

[image]

I have tried implementing my own logic using `pointerInteropFilter` to detect the offset and `verticalScroll` for the scrolling capabilities. But when I include pointerInteropFilter it interacted with the verticalScroll and the Column becomes laggy and does not detect the proper events!

```
Column(
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .offset {
            IntOffset(0, offset.roundToInt())
        } 
        .pointerInteropFilter { motionEvent ->    
            
            when (motionEvent.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    startFingerPositionY = motionEvent.rawY
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    offsetY = startFingerPositionY - motionEvent.rawY
                    startFingerPositionY = motionEvent.rawY    
           
                }
            }    
            true 
        }
        .verticalScroll(state = state)
){
    
}
```

***So it is up to Google to allow custom over-scroll effects, and lets hope in the future, they will do something about it!***

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar requirement recently and after digging through the source code and documentation I ended up with the following solution:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun OverscrollExample() {
    val coroScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    val overscrollEffect = remember(coroScope) { VerticalOverscroll(coroScope) }

    LazyColumn(
        state = listState,
        userScrollEnabled = false,
        modifier =
            Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                .overscroll(overscrollEffect)
                .scrollable(
                    orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                    reverseDirection = true,
                    state = listState,
                    overscrollEffect = overscrollEffect
                )
    ) {
        items(10) { index ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(100.dp).background(Color.Blue)) {
                Text("index: $index")
            }

            Spacer(Modifier.height(32.dp))
        }
    }
}
```

For the overscroll effect I found the example code from the following documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/OverscrollEffect

I modified it a bit for my own look and feel but that's the general idea, you could modify the modifier, the animation used or the calculation used to get your own feel.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
class VerticalOverscroll(val scope: CoroutineScope, val resistance: Float = 0.2f) :
    OverscrollEffect {
    // Here I use a state because for my app I use the overscroll value to
    // further customize other elements in the list, but you can remove that
    // and have a normal `var ... = Animatable(0f)` if you don't need it
    var overscrollY by mutableStateOf(Animatable(0f))

    // Ignore small deltas (< 0.5) as this usually comes from floating
    // point rounding issues and can cause scrolling to lock up
    private fun Float.isDeltaValid(): Boolean = abs(this) > 0.5

    override fun applyToScroll(
        delta: Offset,
        source: NestedScrollSource,
        performScroll: (Offset) -> Offset
    ): Offset {
        val deltaY = delta.y

        val sameDirection = sign(deltaY) == sign(overscrollY.value)

        val undoOverscrollDelta =
            // When scrolling the opposite direction of the overscroll
            // subtract from the overscroll first before scrolling
            if (overscrollY.value.isDeltaValid() && !sameDirection) {
                val oldOverscrollY = overscrollY.value
                val newOverscrollY = overscrollY.value + deltaY

                // If all the overscroll is done and we're now scrolling, clamp the overscroll
                // and return the remaining delta
                if (sign(oldOverscrollY) != sign(newOverscrollY)) {
                    scope.launch { overscrollY.snapTo(0f) }
                    deltaY + oldOverscrollY
                }
                // If there is still overscroll subtract from it and return the full
                // delta so that no scrolling occurs
                else {
                    scope.launch { overscrollY.snapTo(overscrollY.value + deltaY * resistance) }
                    deltaY
                }
            } else {
                0f
            }

        val adjustedDelta = deltaY - undoOverscrollDelta
        val scrolledDelta = performScroll(Offset(0f, adjustedDelta)).y
        val overscrollDelta = adjustedDelta - scrolledDelta

        if (overscrollDelta.isDeltaValid() && source == NestedScrollSource.Drag) {
            scope.launch { overscrollY.snapTo(overscrollY.value + overscrollDelta * resistance) }
        }

        return Offset(0f, undoOverscrollDelta + scrolledDelta)
    }

    override suspend fun applyToFling(
        velocity: Velocity,
        performFling: suspend (Velocity) -> Velocity
    ) {
        val consumed = performFling(velocity)
        val remaining = velocity - consumed

        overscrollY.animateTo(
            targetValue = 0f,
            initialVelocity = remaining.y,
            animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 500, easing = EaseOutQuad)
        )
    }

    override val isInProgress: Boolean
        get() = overscrollY.value != 0f

    override val effectModifier: Modifier =
        Modifier.offset { IntOffset(x = 0, y = overscrollY.value.roundToInt()) }
}
```

[image: Gif showing the overscroll effect on the list top and bottom]