# wrap_content doesn't work on list view

Tags: android, listview

when I set property: android:layout_height of ListView to wrap_content it just wrap first item in the listview:

```
     ...
    <ListView android:id="@+id/points_add_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/points_add_progress"/>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/points_add_progress2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/points_add_list"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

if I use for example 300dp instead of wrap_content, some other items are visible.

my custom view layout XML for list view adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/points_add_row_title"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/PlaneText"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/points_add_row_radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Height of ListView fills the whole screen, although set as wrap\_content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479915/height-of-listview-fills-the-whole-screen-although-set-as-wrap-content)

Comment: I find out if I remove ScrollView, list view shows all items. why?

Comment: I want to add little comment, but my reputation isn't enough to. And my opinion could be wrong. Karakuri's answer on CommonsWare's links is exactly right answer i think.
and this google guy said why we shouldn't use wrap_content on ListView.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&t=40m40s And about your comment, my opinion is that,<br>
ScrollView's height is probably wrap_content with scroll vertically.
If then, ScrollView's height will be adapter's height or ImageView's height. Bcuz, ScrollView doesn't care how many ListItem should be displayed. It only check how many view or groupview is

Comment: thanks a lot, I shouldn't use both scroll view and list view in same place, but my ScrollView's height is mach_parent not wrap_content.