# Moving Footer to Top when ListView Above is Empty

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

On my activity, I want to include a listview and a fragment that will always be included at the bottom of the listview. I initially tried using a scrollview with both inside, but since mixing a scrollview and a listview does not really work, I switched to using the fragment as a footer for the listview instead.

However, my listview is populated by entering data into the fragment and whenever the listview is empty, there's an empty space at the top of the page and the footer goes to the bottom of the screen. I want the footer to be initially at the top of the page when the listview is empty. When one entry is added, the entry should be at the top of the page with the footer right beneath it (not necessarily at the very bottom of the page yet), etc. I hope that makes sense!

Here's the code I'm using to set the footer:

```
 ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.frag_bottom, null);
        listview.addFooterView(footer);
        listview.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_NORMAL);
        listview.setStackFromBottom(true);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should look into viewbinder for your adapter. So instead of a footer per se, you can bind the fragment as the last element in the list. Maybe that will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into that as well! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your ListView's layout params height to *wrap_content*. This way the empty list would be 0 pixels high and the footer view at the top.

Maybe this post helps even better:

[Height of ListView fills the whole screen, although set as wrap_content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479915/height-of-listview-fills-the-whole-screen-although-set-as-wrap-content)

Comment: Works perfectly for me! Thanks for the quick, easy answer :)