# How to trigger the over scroll animation by code?

Tags: android, listview, animation, android-canvas, overscroll

I am trying to trigger the over scroll animation on ListView by code.
[image]

Ripple or Glow (how do you call it?) should appear on the edge.

I tried all the function in ListView like scroll* or scrollSmooth*, non of them could trigger the animation.

I also tried some solutions which could trigger the animation of Ripple background, but it's not the same as this edge effect.

I am new to Android. Please let me know if there are any method, thanks.

I also tried to use onDraw(Canvas canvas), because I didn't find any solution. As I always do this kind of thing on iOS, so I can draw the effect as animation. But here is another problem, the drawing speed is super low, I don't know why, just some typical drawing code on stackoverflow. And when I started a view transition later, everything messed up.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you to use a `RecyclerView` instead for your purpose. The "Overscroll" animation is supported by default.

A `RecyclerView` is in a way pretty similar to a `ListView`, but it makes it for example way easier to deal with animations or forces you to use the `ViewHolder Pattern`. Furthermore it is way more flexible then a `ListView`.

However **in my personal** opinion using a `ListView` over a `RecyclerView` for simple use cases is still fine.

**So what steps are necessary to create one?**

**Adding the dependency**

First add the dependency to your `app.gradle` file. You will find this file under `"Gradle Scripts -> build.gradle (Module: app)"` or by simply pressing `TAB twice` and then entering gradle in the search menu (pretty useful when searching files :) ). There add the following dependency:     `implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'`

Alternatively you can Drag and Drop the RecyclerView from the `Designer` to your Layout (Designer can be found by going to your `layout.xml` file and switching to the `Design Tab`) by searching it (top left). This will automatically add the dependency for you.

**Creating the Layout**

Simply the same as ListView (note: this example does not use `ConstraintLayout` as parent `ViewGroup`):

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvExample"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I don't know if you are currently using a `ConstraintLayout`, but you should definitely check it out :).

**Adapter explained**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleViewHolder> {
private List<String> mData;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

RecyclerViewAdapter(List<String> data, LayoutInflater inflater) {
    mData = data;
    mInflater = inflater;
}

@Override
public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ExampleViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.getTvText().setText(mData.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}
}
```

*onCreateViewHolder*: As it already says a new `ViewHolder` has to be created. **This is not called everytime a new item pops up on screen when scrolling**!

*onBindViewHolder*: Data for the `ViewHolder` given as parameter has to be updated.

*getItemCount*: How many items does this `RecyclerView` consist of?

**ViewHolder**

```
class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
private TextView mTvText;

    public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTvText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
    }

    public TextView getTvText() {
        return mTvText;
    }
}
```

There you just extract your Views so you can update them when the `onBindViewHolder` method is called. Layout for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="56dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</android.support.constraint.FrameLayout>
```

**To finish**
Now you only have to set a `LayoutManager` and an `Adapter` to your `RecyclerView` and voilah! The `LayoutManager` simply tells the `RecyclerView` how those items should be arranged. Ok now let's finish:

```
mRvExample.setHasFixedSize(true); //set this if every item has the same size - performance gain
mRvExample.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
mRvExample.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(Arrays.asList("asdf","asdfsdf"), getLayoutInflater());
```

Whilst I could not directly solve your problem using a `ListView` I hope that I was still able to help you out. Since I don't know which level you are at I hope it was also fine of me to include a description of how to set up a basic `RecyclerView`. Helpful links you should have a look it to get a more in depth understanding are:

Base description:
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Talking about enter animations:
https://proandroiddev.com/enter-animation-using-recyclerview-and-layoutanimation-part-1-list-75a874a5d213

Adding onClick: [RecyclerView onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)

Using Kotlin: https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-adapter-kotlin/

Item decorartion: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/a-view-divided-adding-dividers-to-your-recyclerview-with-itemdecoration/

Pro RecyclerView talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhLVD6iiZQs

Comment: Thank, but you didn't answer my question. I know recycleview, it's pretty similar as CollectionView on iOS. But That's not what I am trying to do.

Comment: Sorry :/ But why do you wanna use ListView?
Its tough to recreate I'd say. this "bumper" has a different curve for different velocities and depending on where you initiate the movement the tip of the curve will move to that initial position (on the y axis) accordingly. I can't promise you it but I'll probably have a look into it cause it sounds like an interesting problem to solve.

However it will take me atleast today and probably tomorrow if not more, because I am a bit busy :/

Comment: Sorry, I think that's common animation on scroll view, not so sure. So, I just pick one of them to test, the listview. 

Comment: Haven't tried it but maybe you should have a look at this :)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201907/android-listviews-bounce-to-scrollview